# Android Studio 3.5.1 can't run app on any device by adb

Tags: android, macbook-pro, android-studio, macos-mojave, adb

I am trying to debug app on my Android Studio(version 3.5.1).
My environment is MacOS 10.14, Macbook Pro.
When I run app on AVD, everything works fine.
However, when I run app on real device, I always get this error:

[android studio app installation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzH6y.png)

Also, after the installation failed, the device disappeared in adb devices list:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFdzi.png)

I have to reconnect the device, then I can see it in adb list again.

I have tried:

- restart Android Studio
- reinstall Android Studio
- reconnect and tried three different android device (all of them not working, and they work fine on other macbook)
- install Android File Transfer

Is there anyway to troubleshooting my Android Studio ADB connection problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with my MacBook Pro (2019). I really don't understand why but you can debug your app in your device (see logs, and use breakpoint) with this easy workaround.

1. Connect your device
2. Build your app (Make project button) but not run it
3. Open finder and go to MyProject/build/outputs/MyProject-debug.apk
4. Send APK file to your device
5. Install this APK directly from your device
6. Start app and you can see logs in logcats et you can attach debugger to your app

Answer (score 0):

I find a new solution and it's work fine for me now !!

In fact my mistake it that is used brew to install adb and android studio. To solve this issue i removed manually all files references of android studio and all references of adb. When i did that i found 2 references of adb in my Mac and i think that was the problem.

So remove all and re-install android studio with the DMG provided by google.

Enjoy